# Filtering through a given date in f#

Tags: date, filter, f#

I am having trouble filtering some data.  I have a a string [] list which has the information shown in the picture I added.  What i need to do, is to compare, for each of the items in the list, the date (which is in format DD/MM/YYYY) (corresponds to the date of creation) to a parameter that is a string called beforeThat (which is another date given by the user) and acording to that filter the the list or creating a new one with the items that where created before the date that beforeThat stablishes.  I am working on f#.  Thanks for the help.

[image: Data]

Comment: Instead of posting a picture, could you please post the code so that we could potentially copy it in order to reproduce your code?

Comment: I am new to this, what part of the code is it that you want?  The program works with a library (given) that has an interface where the user picks the date.

Comment: That part in which you would place a call to `System.DateTime.Parse`, for example, to enable arithmetic operations on dates...

Comment: ill try do something with the system.datetime.parse and then post something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
open System
open System.Globalization

let getItems beforeThat items =
    items |> List.filter (function
        | [|_; _; _; _; s; _|] ->
            match DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None) with
            | true, d -> d < beforeThat
            | _ -> failwith "invalid date/time"
        | _ -> failwith "invalid item"
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
open System
open System.Globalization

let data = [[|""; ""; ""; ""; "1/1/2014"|]; [|""; ""; ""; ""; "5/1/2014"|]]

let beforeThat = DateTime (2014, 1, 3)

let filteredData =
    data
    |> List.filter (fun entry ->
        DateTime.ParseExact (entry.[4], "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < beforeThat
    )
```

I remember that you said in your last question that those are facebook results. Well, this would be one way to get all the entries where the 5th "parameter" is a date before `beforeThat`.

**Explanation:**

`DateTime.ParseExact` needs a format string which has to match the provided date strings. You can read all about the format strings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If the passed string does not match the format, ParseExact will cause an exception, otherwise the returned date is compared to `beforeThat`.

Daniel's answer is essentially the same, but it uses pattern matching to extract the date string from the entry and also uses `TryParseExact`, which will not cause an exception when the passed string is not in the correct format.